# Redirect if form is valid Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

In the following code, I check if the form is valid, and if yes, I want it to redirect to the next page, however it's giving the following error:
AN ERROR OCCURRED
PAGE NOT FOUND
EXCEPTION INFORMATION:
Message: Invalid controller specified (undefined)

Here's the code:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        global $current_user;

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $mapper = new Site_Model_WpTerms();
            $main_categories = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'ptype',true);
            $sizes = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'size',true);
            $genders = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'gender',true);
            $seasons = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'season',true);
            $decades = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'decade',true);
            $colors = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'color',true);
            $styles = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'style',true);
            $materials = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'material',true);
            $patterns = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'pattern',true);
            $others = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'other',true);
            $condition = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'condition',true);
            $shipping = $mapper->fetchTerms(0,'shipping',true);
            $this->view->colors = $colors;
            $form = new Site_Form_Submission($main_categories,$sizes,$genders,$seasons,$decades,$colors,$styles,$materials,$patterns,$others,$condition,$shipping);
            $this->view->form = $form;
            $this->view->finished_settings = self::finishedStep('finished_settings');

            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                if (!$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams())) {
                    $form->populate($this->getRequest()->getParams());
                }else{
                    $this->_helper->redirector('getpaid');
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->_redirect('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . PHOTO_GUIDE);
        }
    }
```

I must mention that I'm using modules in my application.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . PHOTO_GUIDE)` to see what you are trying to redirect to?

Comment: that line works, I'm talking about
`$this->_helper->redirector('getpaid');`

Comment: Is getpaid a controller?

Comment: for that line to work 'getpaid' has to be an action in the current controller. So try `$this->_helper->getHelper(Redirector)->gotoSimple('getpaid','controllerName','moduleName', array(params as key=>value if required));` Also if your $form method is 'POST' validate against `$this->getRequest()->getPost();` not against `getParams()` why validate more then is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');

$this->_redirector->setCode(303)
    ->setExit(false)
    ->setGotoSimple("this-action", "some-controller");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$this->_helper->redirector('action','controller','module');`